# DataTables Set Default sorting column and set unsortable columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Is it possible to set the default column to sort once the page loads? I want to use the one datatable call for different tables across my site. Is it possible to add a `th` class to achieve this?

I also want to disable sorting on some columns and since i'm looking for the one datatables call to do everything, is there a class i can add to the th that will make it unsortable?

This is my called dataTable script

```
if (jQuery().dataTable) {
    $('#table-list-items').dataTable({
        "fnDrawCallback" : function () {
        },
        "aLengthMenu": [
        [10, 15, 25, 50, 100, -1],
        [10, 15, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
        ],
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ Records per page",
            "sInfo": "_START_ - _END_ of _TOTAL_",
            "sInfoEmpty": "0 - 0 of 0",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious": "Prev",
                "sNext": "Next"
            }
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            'bSortable': true,
            'aTargets': [0]
        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: Check out this solution for "unsortable" columns: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20547339/1430996

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As per the [table sorting docs](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html) you can do that using the `order` option:

```js
$('.table-asc0').dataTable({
  order: [[0, 'asc']]
})
```

The 0 indicates to sort on the first column, while `asc` to do it in ascending order. You can chose any other column and use `desc` too.

---

For DataTables versions prior to `1.10` you should use `aaSorting` instead

```js
$('.table-asc0').dataTable({
  aaSorting: [[0, 'asc']]
})
```

To order descending on the first column:

```js
$('.table-asc1').dataTable({
  aaSorting: [[1, 'desc']]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have many tables and in some of them the 2nd or 4th col might need to be sorted. Is it possible to do this by just adding a class?

Comment: Since you can target elems and enable a DataTable with parameters on it, you should call Datatables on the differents class with different parameters, see update.

Comment: Aye I have been doing that so far. Was looking to see if there was a way around it using classes in the HTML instead.

Comment: Like doing only one call to DataTables but with different parameters ?

Comment: Using different ids $('#table-list-items').dataTable({ and $('#table-activity-log').dataTable({

Comment: I tried what you said but got this error "DataTables warning (table id = 'table-list-items'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy"

Comment: Yeah, there is conflicts because you call DataTables on an elem multiples times, you should make sure the jQuery targets don't match an elem twice.

Comment: How is that possbile? The first one is the #id.dataTable and the second which calls the sort is .class.dataTable http://live.datatables.net/urades/edit#javascript,html

Comment: See [link](http://live.datatables.net/urades/2/edit#javascript,html), you have to add the option at the first call, not create another one

Answer (score 24):

**SET INITIAL ORDER** (DataTables 1.10)

Use [`order`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/order) to set initial order of the table.

For example, to sort by second column in descending order:

```js
$('#example').dataTable({
   "order": [[ 1, 'desc' ]]
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcdotmn2/43/) for code and demonstration.

---

**DISABLE SORTING FOR A COLUMN**  (DataTables 1.10)

Use [`columnDefs`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) and [`orderable`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable) to disable sorting on certain columns.

For example, to disable sorting on third and forth columns:

```js
$('#example').dataTable({
   "columnDefs": [
      { "targets": [2,3], "orderable": false }
  ]
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcdotmn2/44/) for code and demonstration.

---

**SET INITIAL ORDER AND DISABLE SORTING FOR THE SAME COLUMN**  (DataTables 1.10)

You can combine [`order`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/order) option to set initial order of the table and [`orderable`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable) to disable sorting on the same column.

For example:

```js
$('#example').dataTable({
   "order": [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
   "columnDefs": [
      { "targets": [0], "orderable": false }
  ]
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcdotmn2/172/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: how about doing the same ?

Comment: and how can you do BOTH? i disabled ordering on my column 0, but want initial ordering done by that exact column... but nothing happens

Answer (score 13):

You can do this via the `data-order` data attribute on the table HTML which will give you the flexibility you need on a table by table basis while still allowing you to use a single call to initialise your dataTables:

```
<table className="table table-condensed table-striped" data-order="[[ 2, &quot;asc&quot; ]]" id="tableId">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col1</th>
          <th>Col2</th>
          <th>Col3</th>
          <th>Col4</th>
          <th>Col5</th>
          <th>Col6</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Val1</td>
          <td>Val2</td>
          <td>Val3</td>
          <td>Val4</td>
          <td>Val5</td>
          <td>Val6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For those troubleshooting this technique, be sure to have lowercase `"asc"` and `"desc"`.

Answer (score 2):

is corect and worked:

```
    $('#admin').DataTable({
        "aaSorting": [[3, 'desc']],
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "columns": [
            {'data' : 'request_code'},
            {'data' : 'name_receiver'},
            {'data' : 'name_area'},
            {'data' : 'created_at'},
            {'data' : 'state'},
            {'data' : 'city'},
            {'data' : 'history'},
        ],
        "ajax": "{{route('my.route.name')}}",
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'print'],
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Include the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tableID').DataTable( {
            "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
        } );
    } 
);
```

Reference:

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

If their has any error like 'DataTables warning for reinitialise' then you can use this. Here 'audit-log' is the table id.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#audit-log') ) {
       table = $('#audit-log').DataTable();
       table.destroy();
    }

    $('#audit-log').DataTable({
       order: [[0, 'desc']]
    });
 });
```