# Disable Sorting on every column except the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

i'm currently using Datatables for a Custom system and i would like to disable Sort for every column but the first one.

I tried with the following code wich is working fine when i add values separated by comma

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
    { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
],
```

But my tables column number vary for each individual file so i can have 3 or maybe 12 columns, and i don't want to have to manually add the values for each file.

If i add more values than the columns i have in one file i get the following error, and an execution stop

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

So, is there any way i can get those index and pass them to the function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a specific class to the TH element that you do not want to be sortable.

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th>
         ...
      </th>
      <th class="no-sort">
         ...
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then you can specify this class in your `aTargets` parameter.

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
    { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': ['no-sort'] }
]
```

View [here](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns) for more information on the Column specific options.

Answer (score 1):

And then you can specify this class in your aTargets parameter.

```js
columnDefs: [ { orderable: false, targets: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and seems more practical (though not exactly elegant)

```
columnDefs: [
  {
    "targets": [0],
    "orderable": true
  }, {
    "targets": [''],
    "orderable": false
  }
]
```